# Is it possible to foot pedal work with HTML Audio player in asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, audio

In my web application, I have already foot pedal and i am playing `.wav` files by using `HTML` Audio Player.

But it is suitable to work with foot pedal using `HTML` Audio Player.

If it is not suitable to work with `HTML` Audio Player can any one please suggest me which audio player to use for work with foot pedal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML5` `<audio>` element specifies a standard way to embed `audio` in a web page.

And you dont need any other thing to play audio in a `Html` web

This element support all of browsers and its easy to use like this code :

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Also it supported `.wav` type of audios

Comment: Hi, i have this Player but what i need is it is support to work with foot pedal or not

Comment: what is the foot pedal ? say about this i'll help you

Comment: Thank you for your help. A foot pedal is a device which has three mechanical switches for play, rewind, and fast forward. People like medical transcriptionists use these devices for playing audio while they keep their hands busy on the keyboard. Any programmer who is developing solutions for such a firm should be able to find a software interface to incorporate the foot pedal device into the application.  and also can you see this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63849/Serial-Foot-Pedal-Device-Server

Comment: sorry . i don't know about this device and how it work . i have't  any idea about relationship of this device and `HTML` .

Comment: @Shiv I think that it depends on specific foot pedal. If it has some interfaces for it so you can do it. Otherwise it's impossible. Especially in the web application becouse your pedal will connect to the user's PC and browser will not work with it without any special app on the user's PC.

Comment: Is it foot pedal work with windows media player. i searched in google i found some article to  windows media player work with foot pedal. i follow all the guidance in that when how can i configured to foot pedal am unable to get that one.Can you please tell me about this which player also suitable for foot pedal